# SSH connection to PostgreSQL-base

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, ssh, proxy, remote-access

I have task of connecting with remote PostgreSQL-base.

Base is located at remote domain: www.remotedomain.com
and hosted at localhost: 5443

A I understand, in this case remotedomain is a proxy for this base.

Domain has (for example) Ip 51.3.151.67 (v4), 2a02:5f7:115:517d::8(v6)

Credentials for www.remotedomain.com login "user" and password "password".

Remote Connection to www.remotedomain.com is provided by ssh
with credentials "root" and "shhpassword".

Entering by ssh, I prescribed in postgresql.conf  listen_addresses = '*'
and in the end of pg_hba.conf    host    all   all  46.4.143.67  md5

In IntelliJ Idea:
[image: To database]
[image: to ssh tunel]

But it returns: "Authentication failed: Exhausted available authentication methods".
My be, its mean, that I have to use key par for proxy auth instead of password?
Or its another reason?

Comment: First, it is called a "database", not a "base". Second, rather than assuming that something is a proxy or requires an SSH tunnel, why don't you ask the DBA for the proper way to connect?

Answer (score 0):

> in the end of pg_hba.conf host all all 46.4.143.67 md5

PostgreSQL stops matching at the first match in the pg_hba.conf file.  Adding a line to the end is unlikely to be the correct thing to do, as it is likely there is a less specific line matching earlier in the file.  And who is 46.4.143.67?

> In IntelliJ Idea:

Where are you running IntelliJ Idea?  Are you running it locally, or ssh into the database's host and running it from there?

> "Authentication failed: Exhausted available authentication methods"

This is not a PostgreSQL error message.  It must be coming from the ssh tunnel attempt failing.

Comment: 46.4.143.67 is IP of domain.

Comment: "Where are you running IntelliJ Idea? Are you running it locally, or ssh into the database's host and running it from there?"   I... dont understand clear question.  I run ssh-connection in terminal (successfully), then I go to Idea and with run

Comment: The problem was in that I uncommented lines in postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf-files. Sorry for troubling - it was a real  foolishness from me.